# help debugging a silverlight application

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, silverlight, visual-studio-2010, debugging

I am currently developing a silverlight application, however yesterday I started getting the following error message every time I run the project:

[image: Webpage Error - Line: 1805 - Error: Object doesn't support this property or method]

I am a little confused as to why I am getting this message, and am looking for some help to track down the cause. If I click "yes" to debug - nothing happens. Also, I have no Line 1805 in any of my source files!

This error message started appearing yesterday, and appears as soon as I run the project, shortly before the first page loads. If i click yes or no, the project then loads and runs perfectly, I cannot see any unwanted behaviour.

I have been using source control, so I rolled back the project to a point before the error started appearing, however I am still getting the error!

Could it be a setting in VS Web Developer Express 2010 that I have accidentally changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answer Anthony, however I just solved the issue.

I cleared the browser cache, and now the error has gone away. How bizarre!

Answer (score 1):

You have script debugging enabled in your IE advanced settings.  If you don't intend to be debugging script then disable it.  The line number represents the line in HTML or Javascript content file where the error is being reported.